# How to remove Facebook username and return to profile ID?

Tags: facebook, username, profile, delete

I want to remove (not change) my Facebook username, so that my profile page should be accessible from my ID number. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the answer provided by Chris, an easier way to get your ID is to enter the URL:

`https://graph.facebook.com/{YOUR_FACEBOOK_USERNAME}`

This will provide you with your ID which you can use with the URL as mentioned by Chris.

`http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id={YOU_FACEBOOK_ID}`

Comment: I'm currently getting a "*(#803) Cannot query users by their username (usernamehere)*" error message when trying this method.

Answer (score 4):

I can't see an option to remove the name, but you can recover your user id and generate a URL from that. It's a bit convoluted, but if you go to a friends profile page you'll see a link

> See friendship

this will have an URL of the form:

> http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=[id number 1]&and=[id number 2]

From experimentation it seems that [id number 1] is your number. Though if you find a friend that hasn't set a profile name for themselves it will be easier to spot. Then you can create the url:

> http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=[id number 1]

Answer (score 2):

You cannot remove your username. Once you have a username the only options are

- Start a new account (most likely you don't want that)
- [Change](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=162586890471598#How-do-I-change-my-username?) to a new username (you can only do this once)

[image: Account Settings]

A third possible (rare) option would be that a Business/entity decides to claim ownership of your username as Facebook reserves the right to reclaim usernames.